# How can I lookup the values in a df column against multiple lists and return the list name in a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with a column called `'color'`, containing a list of colors.

| color |
| --- |
| Red |
| Yellow |
| Green |
| Yellow |
| Violet |

I've created two lists, `primary` and `secondary`. I'm trying to iterate through the values in the 'color' column against the two lists and create a new column `'category'` which contains the list name (or the category `"primary` and `"secondary"`).

```
primary = ["red","yellow","blue"]
secondary = ["green","violet","orange"]
```

This is the output I'm looking for.

| color | category |
| --- | --- |
| Red | primary |
| Yellow | primary |
| Green | secondary |
| Yellow | primary |
| Violet | secondary |

I've tried using two `np.where` statements but the second statement overwrites the first. I now understand why it's doing that but I'm struggling to find a solution to my problem.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `numpy.select` (since the words in `df` are capitalized but those in the lists aren't, we could align them with the `str.lower` method):

```
colors = df['color'].str.lower()
df['category'] = np.select([colors.isin(primary), colors.isin(secondary)], ['primary', 'secondary'], np.nan)
```

Output:

```
    color   category
0     Red    primary
1  Yellow    primary
2   Green  secondary
3  Yellow    primary
4  Violet  secondary
```

Answer (score 1):

With a `lambda` function

```
df['type'] = df.color.apply(lambda col : 'primary' if col.lower() in primary else ('secondary'  if col.lower() in secondary else ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `np.where`:

```
import numpy as np
color["category"] = np.where(color["color"].str.lower().isin(primary), 
                             "primary", 
                             "secondary")

>>> color
    color   category
0     Red    primary
1  Yellow    primary
2   Green  secondary
3  Yellow    primary
4  Violet  secondary
```

Alternatively, with `pandas.where`:

```
color["category"] = "secondary"
color["category"] = (color["category"].where(~color["color"].str.lower().isin(primary))
                                      .fillna("primary")
                    )
```